# setInterval skipping count

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I am writing a script to crack a 10 digit code and have script as:

```
var currNum = 9999999999;
setInterval(function(){
    var tmp = currNum;
    $('#code-box-10').val(Math.floor(tmp%10));
    tmp = tmp /10;
    $('#code-box-9').val(Math.floor(tmp%10));
    tmp = tmp /10;
    $('#code-box-8').val(Math.floor(tmp%10));
    tmp = tmp /10;
    $('#code-box-7').val(Math.floor(tmp%10));
    tmp = tmp /10;
    $('#code-box-6').val(Math.floor(tmp%10));
    tmp = tmp /10;
    $('#code-box-5').val(Math.floor(tmp%10));
    tmp = tmp /10;
    $('#code-box-4').val(Math.floor(tmp%10));
    tmp = tmp /10;
    $('#code-box-3').val(Math.floor(tmp%10));
    tmp = tmp /10;
    $('#code-box-2').val(Math.floor(tmp%10));
    tmp = tmp /10;
    $('#code-box-1').val(Math.floor(tmp%10));
    $("#btn-submit").trigger( "click" );
    currNum--;
},1000);
```

The script just refreshes the page every second but updates the numbers only in the multiples of 5 and that too once in every 5 seconds. For example:

call 1: 9999999999
call 2: 9999999999
call 3: 9999999999
call 4: 9999999999
call 5: 9999999995
call 6: 9999999995
call 7: 9999999995
call 8: 9999999995
call 9: 9999999995
call 10: 9999999990
call 11: 9999999990  and so on

I know that it is not one of the most efficient ones but any ideas on this kind of behavior?

Comment: You missed the tag : [ethics]

Comment: And what does the submit button do that you are clicking? The code could really use a for loop to get rid of the repeated code.

Comment: This will take 30 years to go throught all combinations at the speed of one combination per second. (1000000000 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 365). If you are cracking multiple numbers with an even distribution, the average cracking time is 15 years,

Comment: Even if you manage to bump it up to 100 attempts per second (at which point any good login page is going to block you) its going to take 115 days.

Comment: The page is silly. I am planning to open up multiple tabs and run simultaneously